# Wix Dilemma - is this even possible?

Tags: wix

**My Aim:**

To produce a WiX installer that can stop services before installing its files, install the files and then restart the stopped services

**The problem**

The names of the services can be different each time the installer is run, but they will always have a prefix (prefix|servicename-servername) e.g

coServSamSs-server1 & coServSpooler-server1

coServSamSs-otherserver2 & coServSpooler-otherserver2.

I can only think that running a powershell script from the installer to start/stop these services would be the most viable option, but the next problem is that I would want to include such powershell scripts in the msi, so is it possible to

1. install the script before any other files and then run it to stop the services
2. install the rest of the files
3. run the script again to restart the services

I know that there are custom activities to run a powershell script, although i have not had any luck in doing so (see [Wix - install and then run a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763295/wix-install-and-then-run-a-powershell-script))

Suggestions please? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can there we multiple services on same server like you mentioned coServ-server1, coServ-otherserver2. From these will only one be there or multiple?

Comment: @ Sunil Agarwal, yes there will be multiple services on each server. i have edited my post to reflect this

Comment: PowerShell may be not installed on user's computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom actions with windows command to stop specific services

```
<CustomAction Id="A_StopService" Directory="INSTALDIR" ExeCommand='NET STOP "[SERVICENAME]"' Execute="immediate" Return='ignore'></CustomAction>
```

And as you told you have multiple service, then you can call a custom action written in C# or some other language.
Get the list of services with prefix you want and then inside the loop

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(servicename);

try
{
    if (controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running | controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Paused)
    {
        controller.Stop();

        controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 12));

        controller.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Some message
}
```

Like this stop all the services and once the tasks are done, restart the services.

Comment: If the names of the services are not known in advance, you have to list all the services on the machine and then select only those which start with the required prefix.

You can use `sc` command to manage services.

MSI supports scripts written in JScript and VBScript, and you can implement a custom action in C++.

Comment: @Sunil Agarwal - Thanks for that suggestion, and sorry for such a late reply, got stuck doing other work! I've taken your advice and have added a new wix c# project that contains 2 actions in the CustomAction.cs, 1 to stop the services before InstallFiles, and 1 to start the services before InstallFinalize. i have compiled and ran my msi with logging enabled, the first custom action runs without issue, then the files are installed, but when it comes to running the second i get an error message saying that a required dll could not be run. The installed files are then rolled back as expected....

Comment: ....(continued) When i look at the log, i see "CustomAction StartServicesID returned actual error code 1154 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)" where the installer has tried to run my second custom action. Is the problem coming from the fact that i have 2 actions inside the singular CustomAction.cs? Should i be creating a new .cs file for every custom action that i require?? Your continued help is very much appreciated!

Comment: No, no need to separate .cs file for each custom action. you need to start the services after installfinalize. Try starting service after installfinalize

Comment: well i tried that but got a compilation error saying that the custom action should come before the InstallFinalize, so i have created 2 custom action projects, 1 for each action. i get the desired result doing it this way so i'm happy. Thanks for your help